# Use of Although but together

Tags: meaning

"although but one kind of man was seen to go into it, all kinds and varieties of men came out of it."
I am confused with the meaning of the above sentence. Does this sentence mean that all kinds of men would go except one kind and all kinds would come out of it?

Comment: *But* is used here with the sense "only" - Only one sort of man went in, many sorts of man came out.

Answer (score 1):

The word "but" is using in a rather old-fashioned way, meaning "only"

> The Wicked Witch had but one eye...

So, "Only one sort of man entered" and "All kinds came out".  The meaning is odd, so is probably a metaphor of some kind. But the exact meaning can't be understood without more context.